# Using Pandas to map results of a groupby.sum() to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes - one which is a micro level containing all line items purchased across all transactions (DF1). The other dataframe will be built, with the intention to be a higher level aggregation that summarizes the revenue generated per transaction, essentially summing up all line items for each transaction (DF2).

```
df1
Out[df1]:
   transaction_id item_id amount
0  AJGDO-12304     120     $120
1  AJGDO-12304     40      $10
2  AJGDO-12304     01      $10
3  ODSKF-99130     120     $120
4  ODSKF-99130     44      $30
5  ODSKF-99130     03      $50


df2
Out[df2]
    transaction_id    location_id      customer_id   revenue(THIS WILL BE THE ADDED COLUMN!) 
    0  AJGDO-12304          2131234       1234        $140
    1  ODSKF-99130          213124        1345        $200
```

How would I go about linking the output of a groupby.sum() and assigning it to df2? The revenue column will essentially be the revenue aggregation of df1['transaction_id'] and I want to link it to df2['transaction_id']

Here is what I currently have tried but am struggling with putting together,

```
results = df1.groupby('transaction_id')['amount'].sum()
df2['revenue'] = df2['transaction_id'].merge(results,how='left').value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
lookup = df1.groupby(['transaction_id'])['amount'].sum()
df2['revenue'] = df2.transaction_id.map(lookup)

print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
  transaction_id  location_id  customer_id  revenue
0    AJGDO-12304      2131234         1234      140
1    ODSKF-99130       213124         1345      200
```

Comment: @Grygger Glad I could help. If my answer help you please consider marking it as accepted. This will signal others that your issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use map:

```
lookup = df1.groupby(['transaction_id'])['amount'].sum()
df2['revenue'] = df2.transaction_id.map(lookup)

print(df2)
Output

  transaction_id  location_id  customer_id  revenue
0    AJGDO-12304      2131234         1234      140
1    ODSKF-99130       213124         1345      200
```